# How to get a DOM Window reference for a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: gwt, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am porting a firefox extension to google chrome built using GWT.

In the ***linker***, I need to specify **$wnd** and **$doc** variables.

The equivalent in firefox is as follows:

```
var $wnd = Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/appShellService;1"].getService(Ci.nsIAppShellService).hiddenDOMWindow;
var $doc = $wnd.document;
```

The attribute hiddenDOMWindow as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIAppShellService) returns the (singleton) application hidden window, automatically created and maintained by this AppShellService and is Read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background scripts in Chrome extensions always run inside a window (the background window). So you can just access your own window from the background script:

```js
var $wnd = window;
var $doc = $wnd.document;
```

Comment: This solves the problem of the Background pages. How about (generating) the Content Scripts though? If I understand correctly, they share the DOM of the webpages. How do we get the singleton window for those?

Comment: @SaurabhAgarwal: Content scripts cannot access the background page, already because they run in a different process. You have to use messaging.

Answer (score 0):

There is [getViews()](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getViews) method in chrome.extension API. You can get window's document using this method.